# tree generation for rules in python

Tags: python, tree, rules, parse-tree

I would like to draw a tree like structure using Tkinter for the following data:

```
 S--->NP VGF NP VGNF
 NP--->N_NNP_O_M        
 VGF--->V_VM_VF     
 NP--->N_NNP_S_F        
 VGNF--->V_VM_VNF       

 V_VM_VF--->എത്തി   
 N_NNP_S_F--->സീതയെ 
 V_VM_VNF--->കാണാന്‍    
 N_NNP_O_M--->രാമൻ
```

This is the CFG rules  for a single sentence, it written in a file.

How can i view these rules in the form of tree in python? That is parse tree.

How can I draw the tree using Tkinter in GUI.

**Any help or any hint will be very much appreciated.**

Comment: is there any possibility to draw tree in python???????????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you have a parser if yes.then you will get parsetree when running that parser.

i think you have grammer but no parser..
if yes ....then use parser generaters  to make parser.
  to make parser you must give grammer to generaters...

and after getting parse tree.its easy to draw tree in gui.
nltk is for natural language processing..

Answer (score 0):

yes .but its not clear that what type of data you have and which way must draw
is you want only an image that looks like a tree.
or is it draw with a widget 
if you need to draw that as an image use tkinter.canvas()###
or use as widget tkinter.tree_view

Comment: do u know parse tree concept?????????above spcified rules should be in parse tree...can you plz help me